# check_mysql_query cannot connect to mysql, but works from the command line

Tags: mysql, nagios

I have Nagios 3 running on Debian Wheezy. I am able to run the query the following query from the command line. The credentials for the mysql db are stored in `~nagios/.my.cnf`

```
nagios@intranet:~$ /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_query -H 'myhost.mydomain.com' -q "SELECT cast(AVG(availability)*100 AS DECIMAL(5,2)   ) FROM crm.api_clients;" -w 70:100 -c 40:100
QUERY OK: 'SELECT cast(AVG(availability)*100 AS DECIMAL(5,2)   ) FROM crm.api_clients;' returned 100.000000
```

But when the same command is invoked from Nagios, it can't connect to the database.

The relevant sections of the command and service definition are

```
define command{
        command_name    check_proxy
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_query -H 'myhost.mydomain.com' -q "SELECT cast(AVG(availability)*100 AS DECIMAL(5,2)   ) FROM crm.api_clients;"  -w '$ARG1$' -c '$ARG2$'
}

define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       rds_read_replica
        service_description             Proxy availability
        check_command                   check_proxy!70:100!40:100
}
```

In the web console, I see the following error against the service:

`QUERY CRITICAL: Access denied for user 'nagios'@'172.33.13.112' (using password: NO)`

It works the console when I pass the username and password to the command. But I would like to have the `check_mysql_query` use the credentials stored in `.my.cnf`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nagios will run the plugins with no ENV, and therefore no $HOME set. You can simulate this with `env -i` for manual testing.

You can change your check command to something like `HOME=/home/nagios && /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_query ...` (or whatever the path is).

If you can't get that to work, wrap that whole check_command in a shell script that sets HOME before calling the real plugin. Also be sure to grab the return code and pass it through the wrapper script too.